# How to set a yml sequence config value via drush cset

Tags: drush

When the drupal config value (as defined in .schema.yml) is a sequence what is the correct syntax for `drush config-set` so that the value is a sequence not a simple string? For example, with the devel module
`drush config-get devel.settings error_handlers` returns

`'devel.settings:error_handlers':
  1: 1`

So what is the syntax to set the value to `4: 4`. I have tried lots of combinations, such as 4:4  [4:4]. error_handlers.4 4 but have not hit on the right way yet. I could not find any examples or documentation, so asking here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uh, I love riddles like this! And finally found a way!

---

You first have to delete the `error_handlers` config key.

```
$ drush -y cdel devel.settings error_handlers
```

And then set it again.

```
$ drush -y cset devel.settings error_handlers.4 4
```

Let's check.

```
$ drush cget devel.settings error_handlers
'devel.settings:error_handlers':
  4: 4
```

Yeah!

---

Just `drush -y cset devel.settings error_handlers.4 4` without deleting it first would just append it and you'd end up with `1: 1` and `4: 4` both.

Comment: Thank you @leymannx you are right. I am sure I tried that! I have also confirmed your second point, adding another gives both. Then `cdel devel.settings error_handlers.1` will remove the unwanted one after.